# Urlopen and request.get not going through proxy

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy, urlopen

I am testing to see how I can make requests through my org's proxy, but I am having issues with requests and urlopen not recognizing the proxy when I set it.

Using urlopen like below it will timeout with a connection error. It will go through if before I run the python I run the command `export https_proxy="https://myproxy:000"`, but only if I run that command before it. It won't use the proxy I set within the file.

```
import urllib
import ssl

prox = urllib.request.getproxies()
authinfo = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()

proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({"https" : "https://myproxy:000"})

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support, authinfo, urllib.request.CacheFTPHandler)

urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

f = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com/', context=ssl._create_unverified_context())

print(prox)
print(f)
```

For trying it with requests I get the error `urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1131)`. I get this error even when I run the export command like above.

```
import requests
proxies = {
    'https': 'https://myproxy:000'
}

r = requests.get('https://google.com/', proxies=proxies, verify=False)

print(r)
```

I have tried solutions mentioned in other questions about the ssl error like installing ndg-httpsclient, pyasn1, and pyOpenSSL or checking my TLS version. I have the modules installed and my TLS version is 1.3. Any help or direction on how to resolve these proxy issues would be appreciated. I've included a pip list of what's installed for convenience.

```
Authlib            1.2.1
certifi            2023.7.22
cffi               1.15.1
charset-normalizer 3.2.0
cryptography       37.0.4
idna               3.4
ndg-httpsclient    0.5.1
pip                21.3.1
pyasn1             0.5.0
pycparser          2.21
pyOpenSSL          22.0.0
requests           2.31.0
semantic-version   2.10.0
setuptools         68.1.2
setuptools-rust    1.6.0
tornado            6.3.3
typing_extensions  4.7.1
urllib3            2.0.4
wheel              0.41.2
```

Comment: It's too difficult debug your proxy